# javascript returns 1 hour behind calendar date

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have the below javascript to retrieve Start date time and an End date time for an event.

```
while(liEnum.moveNext())
{
    var oLiCal=liEnum.get_current();  
    var localDate =  moment();                               
    var eventDate = oLiCal.get_item("EventDate");
    var eventEndDate = oLiCal.get_item("EndDate");
    var eventAllDayEvent = oLiCal.get_item('fAllDayEvent');
    var eventCompanyWideEvent = oLiCal.get_item('CompanyWideEvent');

    console.log("local date: " + localDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a') );
    console.log("Event Start date: " + moment(eventDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));
    console.log("Event End date: " + moment(eventEndDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));
```

The calendar has the following date and times of an event:

[image]

The console log shows the following:

[image]

As we can see the date start and end times retrieved via javascript is 1 hour behind. 
Can any one please tell why that would be the case, and how can I get the exact date time from the server.

Much Obliged.

Comment: can you share moment() function

Comment: moment is a js library that I'm using and link for this library is, http://momentjs.com/. If I hover on the variables eventDate and eventEndDate by start debugging in IE. I get the hours 1 hour behind then that of the calendar item.

Comment: I had similar issues and documented them here http://yetanothersharepointblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/timezone-issues-when-working-with-dates-in-sharepoints-rest-services/

Answer (score 6):

SharePoint displays date/time according to TimeZone in Regional Settings but returns in UTC format in JSOM.

## Using `SP.TimeZone.Information`

The folloiwing example demonstrates how to retrieve time zone offset using `SP.TimeZone.Information` and then convert to SharePoint date/time using `moment().zone()`:

```
var listTitle = 'Calendar';

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(1);
context.load(item);

var timeZone = web.get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone();
context.load(timeZone);

context.executeQueryAsync(
 function() {
    var eventDate = item.get_item('EventDate');
    var endDate = item.get_item('EndDate');

    var timeZoneOffset = getTimeZoneOffset(timeZone); //exract TimeZone Offset

    var localEventDate = moment(eventDate).zone(timeZoneOffset);
    var localEndDate = moment(endDate).zone(timeZoneOffset);


    console.log("Event Start date: " + localEventDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));
    console.log("Event End date: " + localEndDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));

  },
  logError
);  

function logError(sender,args)
{
    console.log(args.get_message());
}


function getTimeZoneOffset(timeZone)
{
   return  timeZone.get_information().get_bias() +    timeZone.get_information().get_daylightBias() + timeZone.get_information().get_standardBias();          
}
```

### Using `SP.TimeZone.utcToLocalTime`

[SP.TimeZone.utcToLocalTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245318(v=office.15).aspx) - converts the specified DateTime value from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to local time

The following example demonstrates how to use `SP.TimeZone.utcToLocalTime`:

```
var listTitle = 'Calendar';

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(1);
context.load(item);

var timeZone = web.get_regionalSettings().get_timeZone();
context.load(timeZone);


context.executeQueryAsync(
 function onSucceeded() {
    var eventDate = item.get_item('EventDate');
    var endDate = item.get_item('EndDate');

    var localEventDate = timeZone.utcToLocalTime(eventDate);
    var localEndDate = timeZone.utcToLocalTime(endDate);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          console.log(localEventDate.get_value());   
          console.log(localEndDate.get_value());   
      },
      logError       
    );

 },
 logError
);  

function logError(sender,args)
{
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```